# Custom margin for \listoftables and \listoffigure

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, margins

I am using document class book and adding list of tables and list of figure using code below in TOC

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

I want to remove the extra space from the top margin and space between title list of tables and where tables start,
[image: code]

What is expected by the university is
[image: expected]

Comment: There are two apporaches.  You can use a package like titletoc or you can modify `\l@table` (which does the actual formatting).

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I read the pdf for titletoc, but unable to figure out how to reduce the space, please can you assist with the command, that I read more on.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the captions have no titles, just "Table 1:".  Or they do allow titles but just didn't show them in the example.  If not, then `\l@table` will have to ignore the title and just use `\numberline` (doable using saveboxes, but more complicated).  Note that the margins (`\leftskip` and `\rightskip`) include the table and page numbers.

It turns out thet `\@dottedtocline` cannot add a right margin, so had to format everything.  OTOH, the only thing I changed with `\listoftables` was to replace `\chapter*{\listtablename}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}}% as opposed to 1.1, 1.2 etc.

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@table[2]{% #1 = title (with \numberline), #2 = page
  \def\numberline##1{\leavevmode\llap{Table~##1: }}%
  \leftskip=0.5in% left margin
  \rightskip=0.75in% right margin
  {#1}\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill% dotted line
  \rlap{ #2}\par}

\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \if@twocolumn% probably not needed
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    %\chapter*{\listtablename}% defalt title
    \null\vskip\baselineskip
    \noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering
      LIST OF TABLES\\
      \vskip\baselineskip
      (There is no bold or italics text on LOT)}\par
    \null\hfill\makebox[0.75in][l]{ PAGE}\par
      \thispagestyle{plain}%
      \@mkboth{% sets header
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{lot}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}% add to toc
\listoftables

\mainmatter
\chapter{Start}
Some text.

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are required to use double spacing for the entire document, you will need the setspace package and may need to revise the spacing.  I find it amusing that universities go to such lengths to make it look like dissertations are still being cranked out on mechanical typewriters (or MS wprd).